# max, min gradient and other terms in Neural Network

Tags: terminology, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

[This  link](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/mnist.html)  contains a demo that trains a Convolutional Neural Network on the MNIST digits dataset in browser.

I am not getting below terms-
1. max, min gradient in each layer.
2.max, min activation in layers[image]

3.Forward time per example

4.Backprop  time per example

5. Classification loss
6. L2 (a pooling mechanism??! but what this means?) Weight decay loss[image]

   ***What are the meanings of above terms according to given context (webpage demo)?***

Comment: You're asking about 6 different questions here.  We generally prefer posts that ask a single question.  Some of these questions may be off-topic here because they are specific to a particular implementation.  Some of these can probably be answered by doing some research/searching on the name provided there.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to read an introduction to neural networks. I like [neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/), but I can also recommend chapter 4.3 of [my bachelors thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09030.pdf#page=32).

> 1. max, min gradient in each layer

The gradient is like the derivative for high-dimensional functions. Imagine it as an arrow on a landscape. The arrow points into the direction of the steepest ascent, we want to go into the other direction (where the error becomes smallest).

> 2.max, min activation in layers

The activation is $\sum w_i x_i$ ([details](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/11064/8820) and [my BS thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09030.pdf#page=35)). Hence it is what each neuron returns, before the activation function is applied. Now you have many neurons per layer and hence a set of activations $A$. Hence you can take the min / max of it. I don't know why you would take the min, but the maximum might give you an indicator which neurons are "responsible" for which feature.

For CNNs, a complete feature map is usually considered to be one neuron (see [my MS thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf#page=36) for some more details). In your case, it simply seems to be the maximum feature returned (hence the brightest pixel; see input layer)

> 3.Forward time per example

Measure how long it takes to process the input of a neural network.
(There is also the backward pass for the gradient)